# Desactivar Boton en Jtable

Tags: java, java-swing

llevo algo de tiempo realizando una tabla en Java.
El tema es que necesito ayuda, ya que necesito "deshabilitar" un boton (que esta integrado en la tabla) si en la COLUMNA comentario corresponde a "Rechazo".

Ojalá puedan ayudarme..comparto el código.

```
public void llamarMuestra() throws SQLException {
 //   tblDatos.setDefaultRenderer (Object.class, new MiRender()); 
    tblDatos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());   //LLAMA CLASE RENDER QUE GENERA LOS BOTONES
    tblDatos.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.WIDTH);

    setVisible(true);
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Modificar");
    btn1.setName("modificar");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Eliminar");
    btn2.setName("eliminar");
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable(modelo);

    trsfiltro = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
    tblDatos.setRowSorter(trsfiltro);
     String query = ("SELECT m.idMuestras, m.nregistro, c.nombrecliente, m.matriz, m.fechaingresolaboratorio, m.laboratorioejecutante, m.estado, m.observaciones,m.comentario "
            + "FROM muestras m "
            + "INNER JOIN clientes c ON m.fk_idcliente = c.idClientes WHERE m.laboratorioejecutante LIKE 'LADIOX' ");
    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet ResultSet = pst.executeQuery();
    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID Muestras", "Numero Registro", "Cliente", "Matriz", "Analisis", "Ingreso Laboratorio", "Laboratorio Ejecutante", "Estado", "Comentario Rechazo", "Modificar", "Eliminar"});  //creo el nombre de la columna
        try {
            while (ResultSet.next()) {
                int a = ResultSet.getInt("m.idMuestras");
                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{ResultSet.getInt("m.idMuestras"), ResultSet.getInt("m.nregistro"), ResultSet.getString("c.nombrecliente"),
                    ResultSet.getString("m.matriz"), Listaanalisis(a), ResultSet.getDate("m.fechaingresolaboratorio"),
                    ResultSet.getString("m.laboratorioejecutante"), ResultSet.getString("m.estado"), ResultSet.getString("m.comentario"), btn1, btn2});
                btn2.repaint();
            }
            tblDatos.setModel(modelo);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);
            modelo.fireTableDataChanged();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TableroMuestraLADIOX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            System.out.println("error con tabla");
        }
    }
```

CON EL CODIGO DE ARRIBA GENERO LA TABLA Y CARGO LOS DATOS
Y AHORA COMPARTO EL RENDER PARA LA CREACION DEL BOTON DENTRO DE LA TABLA

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Modelo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class Render extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {


        // CREA BOTON DENTRO DE TABLA
        if (value instanceof JButton) {
            JButton btn = (JButton) value;
            if (isSelected) {
                btn.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                btn.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                btn.setForeground(table.getForeground());
                btn.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }
            return btn;
        }
        if (value instanceof JCheckBox) {
            JCheckBox ch = (JCheckBox) value;
            return ch;
        }


        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                hasFocus, row, column); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
//        return null;


    }
```

Comment: Puedes subir una imagen de tu programa? ya me hago una idea de lo que quieres.

Comment: ¿la columna comentario es el checkbox o es el texto?

Comment: btn1.setEnabled(ResultSet.getInt("m.comentario")!="Rechazo" ) o puede ser JButton btn3 = new JButton("Modificar"); btn3.setEnabled(false); y agregas el botón que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Solo utiliza el método `setEnable` antes de agregar estos botones al modelo de la tabla, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
btn1.setEnabled(false);
btn2.setEnabled(false);
```

El codigo completo quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
public void llamarMuestra() throws SQLException {
 //   tblDatos.setDefaultRenderer (Object.class, new MiRender()); 
    tblDatos.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());   //LLAMA CLASE RENDER QUE GENERA LOS BOTONES
    tblDatos.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.WIDTH);

    setVisible(true);
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Modificar");
    btn1.setName("modificar");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Eliminar");
    btn2.setName("eliminar");
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable(modelo);
    btn1.setEnabled(false);
    btn2.setEnabled(false);
    trsfiltro = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
    tblDatos.setRowSorter(trsfiltro);
     String query = ("SELECT m.idMuestras, m.nregistro, c.nombrecliente, m.matriz, m.fechaingresolaboratorio, m.laboratorioejecutante, m.estado, m.observaciones,m.comentario "
            + "FROM muestras m "
            + "INNER JOIN clientes c ON m.fk_idcliente = c.idClientes WHERE m.laboratorioejecutante LIKE 'LADIOX' ");
    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet ResultSet = pst.executeQuery();
    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID Muestras", "Numero Registro", "Cliente", "Matriz", "Analisis", "Ingreso Laboratorio", "Laboratorio Ejecutante", "Estado", "Comentario Rechazo", "Modificar", "Eliminar"});  //creo el nombre de la columna
        try {
            while (ResultSet.next()) {
                int a = ResultSet.getInt("m.idMuestras");
                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{ResultSet.getInt("m.idMuestras"), ResultSet.getInt("m.nregistro"), ResultSet.getString("c.nombrecliente"),
                    ResultSet.getString("m.matriz"), Listaanalisis(a), ResultSet.getDate("m.fechaingresolaboratorio"),
                    ResultSet.getString("m.laboratorioejecutante"), ResultSet.getString("m.estado"), ResultSet.getString("m.comentario"), btn1, btn2});
                btn2.repaint();
            }
            tblDatos.setModel(modelo);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            tblDatos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);
            modelo.fireTableDataChanged();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TableroMuestraLADIOX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            System.out.println("error con tabla");
        }
    }
```

Te recomiendo que en cada fila que se cree utilizar varias instancias de botones, no solo btn1 ni btn2, ya que si quieres agregar un evento que sea diferente para cada uno de estos, tendrás problemas, ya que serán prácticamente objetos bajo la misma instancia, pero eso ya depende de ti y de lo que quieras hacer.